# Restore the root site as site collection with in the same web application using power shell?

Tags: 2013, powershell, restore

we migrated the sites from 2003 to 2013,in 2013 i am having root site i want to move the root site to site collection with in the same web application using power shell.
I used the command after taken back up

```
Restore-SPSite -Identity "newly created site collection url"  -path "D:\backsite.bak"
```

once i ran this command i am getting the error like "Restore-SPSite: another site collection with name already exists use -force to overwrite the existing site collection "

Again i ran with using -Force command after few minutes again it was throwing error like "we can not rename the site collection"

Comment: what url you are using for new site collection? are their any site collection exist on that url? your new url should be looks like this http://webappname.com/sites/name...

Comment: Yes i created same like that only.

Comment: ont hat link do you have any site collection?

Comment: on that web application i am having 10+ site collections

Comment: one more thing, do you want to make the copy of site collection or move it to new location and delete from root?

Comment: that's fine but for that specific link / URL(on which you trying to restore the root site collection), do you already have site colletion?

Comment: I created a new site collection only,once i restore the root site to new site collection i will delete the root site.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18552/discussion-between-phani-and-waqas-sarwar-mcse).

Comment: Did you manage to do a restore-spsite at root level ( "/" ) ? As I need to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Did you remove the original root site collection before running the `Restore-SPSite`?
If not, you also need to specify a new Content database for the Site Collection.

> The Restore-SPSite cmdlet performs a restoration of the site
>   collection to a location specified by the Identity parameter. A
>   content database may only contain one copy of a site collection. If a
>   site collection is backed up and restored to a different URL location
>   within the same Web application, an additional content database must
>   be available to hold the restored copy of the site collection.

So maybe what you want to do is to:

1. [Backup-SPSite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607901(v=office.15).aspx)
2. Delete site collection (root in this case)
3. [Restore-SPSite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607788(v=office.15).aspx)
4. Create a new root site collection.

If you want to restore a backup of a site collection in the same Web Application without deleting the original one you can try running the Restore-SPSite with the following parameters `DatabaseName` and `DatabaseServer`. Pointing to another content DB than the one the site collection was originally on.

so something like this `Restore-SPSite http://server_name/sites/site_name -Path C:\Backup\site_name.bak -Force -DatabaseServer SQLBE1 -DatabaseName SQLDB1`

Comment: Hi Robban1980, I checked root site having different database name and newly created site collection  having different database name.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, you already created a new Site Collection and trying to overwrite with root level site collections. In this case you have two choices.

Method: 1

- Create a new Content Database
- restore the site collection to newly created Database(using the database parameter of Restore command). You can not restore a site collection two times in a content database.
- delete the root site collections.
- Create root level Site collection(if you forget to create a root level site collection other site will suffered.)

**Method :2**

- Backup root site collection
- Delete the Site collection(root)
- Restore the site to new location
- Create root level Site collection(if you forget to create a root level site collection other site will suffered.)